# How to set the initial state value after fetching data to update a form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I've tried to fetch data using "setData" and then using the state variable "data" to set the values of title , desc and author but I'm getting them as undefined. After setting the initial states to empty I've set the values of the input fields to what I had got from the "data" state and when I submit the form only the fields in which the changes are made were updated the rest of the fields had "undefined" values i.e when I submitted the form to update it looked like this {title:undefined,desc:undefined,author:"person1"}, I'm unable to set the initial state values to input field values.

EditBlog.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useParams, useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

const EditBlog = () => {

    const { id } = useParams()

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/values/' + id)
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setData(data)
            })
    }, [id])


    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    const [title, setEditTitle] = useState()
    const [desc, setEditDesc] = useState()
    const [author, setEditAuthor] = useState()


    const history = useHistory()


    const updateHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const updatedBlog = { title, desc, author }
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/values/' + id, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(updatedBlog)
        })
            .then(() => {
                console.log(updatedBlog)
                history.push("/")
            })
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                <h1>Edit Blog</h1>
                <form onSubmit={updateHandler} className="new-blog">

                    <label>Blog Title</label>
                    <div className="input-box">
                        <input
                            onChange={(e) => setEditTitle(e.target.value)}
                            type="text"
                            defaultValue={data.title}
                            className="inputField"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <label>Blog Body</label>
                    <div className="input-box">
                        <textarea
                            onChange={(e) => setEditDesc(e.target.value)}
                            cols="64"
                            defaultValue={data.desc}

                        />
                    </div>

                    <label>Blog Author</label>
                    <div className="input-box">
                        <input
                            onChange={(e) => setEditAuthor(e.target.value)}
                            className="inputField"
                            type="text"
                            defaultValue={data.author}

                        />
                    </div>
                    <button>Save</button>

                </form>
            </div>


        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default EditBlog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing yourself by trying to keep two copies of the same data in state.  Reduce the state to just the one object you're editing (and give it initial values for the inputs, so nothing is `undefined`):

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  title: '',
  desc: '',
  author: ''
});
```

Have your inputs use and update the values in that state object:

```
<input
  onChange={(e) => setData({...data, title: e.target.value})}
  type="text"
  value={data.title}
  className="inputField"
/>
```

Note the use of `value={data.title}` so the input always shows the current value, and the new `onChange` which updates the same state being used and just changes the one value in that state object.

Then when you post the form, simply post the current state instead of building a new object from separately tracked values:

```
body: JSON.stringify(data)
```

---

In short, you don't need or want these:

```
const [title, setEditTitle] = useState()
const [desc, setEditDesc] = useState()
const [author, setEditAuthor] = useState()
```

Because you already have your data in `data`.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In `useEffect` add this code in `.then` block after `setData(data)`:

```
setEditTitle(data.title)
setEditDesc(data.description)
setEditAuthor(data.author)
```

And replace `defaultValue={data.title}` with `value={title}` and the other two  in the same way.

**Note**: I would say that The best approach is to avoid using `states` for your fields as you are already saving the `state` in `useData`. You should modify your code to avoid having three different `state` hooks.

Comment: Thank you this worked well.